# Make document title change visible in chrome with javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, title

I'm trying to change the document title using

```
document.title = "My Shiny New Title"
```

But the change is not visible in Chrome 51.0.2704.106 (Official Build) (64-bit)  It does show as changed in the javascript console or when I use alert, but not in the tab area (next to the favicon).

I've found numerous reports that this isn't normal behavior for a web browser, yet I know websites that do change the title.  If anyone knows of a workaround for this bug, I'd be extremely grateful.

Comment: This works for me.

Comment: when are you changing it?

Comment: Maybe this: http://heyman.info/2010/oct/7/google-chrome-bug-when-setting-document-title/

Comment: @epascarello immediately when my <script> runs.

Comment: Maybe if you delay to to page load, document ready? Just stab in the dark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It now works, after rebooting the computer (I turned it off overnight).  I believe Chrome must have cached the title of my webpage.