# Why can't I change document.title in vue-router?

Tags: javascript, android, vue.js, vue-router, vue-cli

I am trying to change document.title in vue-router, below is my code:

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    if (to.meta.title) {
        document.title = to.meta.title
    }
    next()
})
```

This works fine in iOS, but not so well in android.

I opened the page in an app,and this is the browser's userAgent

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 8.0.0; FRD-AL10 Build/HUAWEIFRD-AL10; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/70.0.3538.110 Mobile Safari/537.36 _MAPP_/5.5.2xmxing
```

In android sometimes the page title doesn't change, but the code in the mounted hook returns the correct result.

```
mounted() {
    alert(document.title)
}
```

Why is it so?

Comment: Can you build a MVCE in codesandbox?

Comment: @Trent here [title test](https://codesandbox.io/s/lrm8yk1mwm).But this only has problems in the application and is correct in the computer browser.

Comment: All browsers or just chrome?

Comment: @Trent Just chrome

Comment: Not something silly like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38852457/make-document-title-change-visible-in-chrome-with-javascript

Comment: @Trent Maybe, now I suspect it's the app, because there's no such thing in the browser that comes with the phone